# Is the bicoin: URI scheme an URL scheme as well?

Tags: bip21-uri

Hi given that bitcoin:1335STSwu9hST4vcMRppEPgENMHD2r1REK is a valid URI. Is it a valid **URL** (locator!) as well?

I tend to say yes when I compare sending bitcoins to a `bitcoin:` URI with sending mails to a `mailto:` URI. The latter is according to [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) an URL scheme.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225). Bitcoin doesn't reply fit any of these perfectly, but I think it is a URI in that it uniquely identifies a Bitcoin account. The issue is that Bitcoin doesn't really have a location function. I suppose you could say that you can locate Bitcoin address history, but that's not really the purpose of a `bitcoin:` link. I'm going to say no, it is not a URL. It is however a URN.

EDIT: `mailto:` is a URL the same way a HTTP URL is. It has a domain name and states the location for sending something. Given this example, I'll change my answer to yes.

Comment: I updated my question with a `mailto` URL scheme comparison. You still tend to no?